# JQuery Selecting within a Set

Tags: jquery

I have more than one control of the same type, with 'xyz' in the middle of the ID:

```
    <input type="text" id="AutoStuff_hfyrt_xyz_MoreStuf_123" />
    <input type="text" id="AutoStuff_fyhrt_xyz_MoreStuf_7" />
```

If I want the one ending in '123,' I thought that would be:

```
    var x = $("input[id*='xyz']").("[id$='123']").val()
```

But I get an error, "Identifier expected."

Answer (score 2):

You can either use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) or simply combine the two using the [Multiple Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/).

```
// Using .filter()
var x = $("input[id*='xyz']").filter("[id$='123']").val();

// Using the Multiple Attribute Selector
var x = $("input[id*='xyz'][id$='123']").val();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NVwPL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var x = $("input[id*='xyz']").$("[id$='123']").val();
```

or

```
var x = $("[id$='123']", $("input[id*='xyz']")).val();
```

in the second case, you might need to switch arguments or the order of selectors.

Answer (score 0):

var x = $('#AutoStuff_hfyrt_xyz_MoreStuf_123') would be the selector. [] are used for attributes so I think maybe that could be what's causing that error.

```
[attr] has attribute
[attr=val] has attribute with value val
[attr!=val] does not have attribute with value val
[attr^=val] attribute begins with val
[attr$=val] attribute ends with val
[attr*=val] attribute includes val
[attr~=val] attribute includes val as a word
[attr|=val] attribute begins with val and optional hyphen
```

from the jquery pocket-guide.